# Guatemalans: what does "Huebon" mean?

Tags: vocabulario, diferencias-regionales, insultos, guatemala

I work with a cute boy who is from Guatemala, we like each other and flirt back and forth every day! But he speaks only a little English and I know **very** little Spanish. Today he messaged me and said:

> huebon

but he won't tell me what it means! My friend from Venezuela said it means "lazy" but another one of my friends says in Guatemala and in this context it's meant to be playful and endearing?

Comment: Consider reading [Is “weón” used in Chile and what does it mean?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/4801/5481). Check in [this answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/5313/5481): "you can write it as hueón, huevón, güeón, güevón or weón" and it lists some meanings

Answer (score 3):

[*Huevón*](https://dle.rae.es/huev%C3%B3n) can be an insult (meaning "lazy", "stupid", or "jerk") but in many Latin American dialects has taken on a secondary meaning of endearment (cf. *[tío](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22848/por-qu%c3%a9-t%c3%ado-designa-cari%c3%b1osamente-a-una-persona-pr%c3%b3xima), [hombre](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21202/can-hombre-be-translated-to-hey), colega, [tronco](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26883/c%c3%b3mo-ha-llegado-tronco-a-ser-sin%c3%b3nimo-de-t%c3%ado-colega-amigo)*), similar to *boludo, loco* and English [*dude*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dude#English):

> Origin uncertain, though likely derived from *doodle* (“fool, simpleton, mindless person”)... the word is first attested in 1883 as a New York City slang term of contempt for a “fastidious man, fop”.

It is variously spelled [huevón](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=huev%C3%B3n), [güevón](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=g%C3%BCev%C3%B3n), [güebón](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=g%C3%BCeb%C3%B3n), [güeón](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=g%C3%BCe%C3%B3n), [weón](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/we%C3%B3n), with some spellings being region specific.

Comment: And in a context where it is used isolated (but as part of a chat), it probably expresses that OP or something OP did is/was "remarkable", either in a good or a bad way. E.g. some thing unusual, or something great, or a mistake, etc.